# Prove that $(\mathbb Z_{10},∔,⨰)$ is a ring where the operations $∔$ and $⨰$, $\mathbb Z_{10}×\mathbb Z_{10}→\mathbb Z_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Starting ring and field theory and need a hand understanding how to prove a ring under its axioms. I have to prove $(\mathbb Z_{10},∔,⨰)$ is a ring where
$$a∔b=a+b+7,\quad a⨰b=ab+7(a+b)+2.$$

So far I have that it must be an abelian group, so associative, commutative. have an additive identity and an additive inverse (A1), i.e.
$$(a∔b)∔c=a∔(b∔c).$$
LHS: $$(a∔b)∔c=(a+b+7)∔c=a+b+c+7.$$
RHS: $$a∔(b∔c)=a∔(b+c+7)=a+b+c+7.$$ 
so it is associative.

Commutative: $$a∔b=b∔a.$$
RHS:
$$b∔a=b+a+7.$$
LHS:
$$a∔b=a+b+7.$$
So commutative.

I am not entirely sure how to show the identities as surely it is obvious that $a∔0=0$ and $a∔(-a)=0$?

Then I think axiom 2 and 3 are fine. I just do not understand how to show the basics here.

Comment: You've missed a $7$ when checking associativity. As for identity, it seems that $a+_R 0 = a + 0 + 7$ (using $+_R$ for addition defined above, $+$ for regular addition), but $a+7 \neq a$ is not true for all $a$. Maybe the additive identity is not $0$ but some other element of the ring...

Answer (score 1):

> I am not entirely sure how to show the identities as surely it is obvious that a∔0=0 and a∔(−a)=0?

Obvious as in without thinking we will just say so?  Tempting, perhaps, but not a very good habit. Or obvious if you think $0\dotplus 0 = 0+0+7=0$, so that $7=0$. Perhaps not so obvious.

To find the additive and multiplicative identities (if they exist!) you should just *write out what that means*, by which I mean

$a\dotplus z=a+z+7=a$ and $a\dot\times e=ae+7(a+e)+2=a$ and then take a look. There are only 10 elements in this case, after all.

---

There is a different way to prove this, one that's used multiple times throughout the site in similar questions. Did you encounter them when searching for your question, initially?

Let $\phi:\mathbb Z_{10}\to \mathbb Z_{10}$ be given by $x\mapsto x+3$. Clearly this map is a bijection of sets.

Moreover, you can check that

$\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)\dotplus\phi(b)$ and $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\dot\times\phi(b)$

From here it is trivial to verify that because $+,\times$ constitute ring operations on $\mathbb Z_{10}$, then $\dotplus, \dot\times$ constitute ring operations on $\phi(\mathbb Z_{10})=\mathbb Z_{10}$, and in fact $\phi$ is an isomorphism of rings viewed this way.

This is called "transport of structure."  The idea is that any bijection of a ring with a set can be used to "force" a ring structure upon the set simply by multiplying things the way they behave in the ring whose structure we are transporting.

Comment: This is it. One may think of this as taking the original structure on $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$, but changing the coordinatization, so that now the neutral element ($0$) is displaced by three units.